# Unable to link a node with itself using Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

How can I create a relationship from a node to itself? I have one node (p:person) and my csv has 2 columns: **name** and **vice**. Each row in my csv represents a person who a ceo and their vp at the time. Now sometimes vp were ceo so I want to show that relationship. Here is what I was trying but no luck. If I do not include the WITH I receive error saying I need it but when I add the * or a property, it says it cannot find row. I'm stuck

```
:auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///ceo_vp.csv' AS row 

CREATE (p:person {name:coalesce(row.name,'UNK')})
MATCH (p:person {name:row.vice })
WITH * 

CREATE (p)-[:was_vp_for]->(p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is typo on the variable p; You must assign a different variable name for vp. Here is the script;

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///ceo_vp.csv' AS row 

MERGE (ceo:person  {name:coalesce(row.name,'UNK')})
MERGE (vice:person {name:row.vice })
CREATE (vice)-[:was_vp_for]->(ceo)
```

Notice that I used merge because as you said, a vp can be a former ceo (and vice versa) so merge is better than create.  Merge will ignore the person if it already exists.

Comment: You want to be careful that the names (spelling, format, etc) are the same for the ceo and vp columns if they are going to re-appear. If, for instance, the same person has a different format when vp and ceo then you will get duplicate nodes for that person.

Comment: The assumption is that csv file is clean and correctly formatted and spelling. I focus more on the question of the SO post rather validating the csv file. I can add a trim function to remove spaces on the names but it is not required. He can figure it out by himself.

Comment: Worked perfect! Thank you. I knew it was something simple I was overlooking

Comment: I have already cleaned the CSV so that the name is good, and they came from same source....thanks for help

Comment: Glad it worked!